# Why is the sodium doublet evidence of electron subshells?

Tags: electrons, spectroscopy

My teacher said that the doublet seen in the sodium emission spectrum is evidence of subshells within the atom.  If this is the case, surely it should be a triplet as there are 3p orbitals so each transition would leave a distinct line on the spectrum?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244632/123208 Also see http://hyperphysics.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/sodzee.html#c2

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure

Comment: You can see my photo of the resolved sodium D lines doublet here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678.